# Jacobian of parametric surface $s(u,v)$ w.r.t. basis in $R^3$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F$ be an unknown function: $$F:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3: (x,y,z)\mapsto (F_x(x,y,z), F_x(x,y,z), F_x(x,y,z))$$ and let $S$ be a parametric surface described by: $$s:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3:(u,v)\mapsto (s_x(u,v), s_y(u,v), s_z(u,v)).$$

Now let $f$ be a known function that approximates the value of $F$ on the surface $S$: $$f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3: (u,v)\mapsto (f_x(u,v), f_y(u,v), f_z(u,v))$$ $$f(u,v)\approx F(S(u,v))$$

Ideally I would like to compute the Jacobian of $F$ along the surface $S$, i.e.  $J_F(s(u,v))$; However as $F$ is inaccessible this is not possible. So instead I would like to get an approximation to $J_F$ using $f$.

Let $q$ be a function: $$q:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2:(x,y,z)\mapsto (q_u(x,y,z), q_v(x,y,z))$$ such that: $$(x,y,z) = s(q(x,y,z))$$ holds on the surface $S$ and obviously $q$ would be undefined outside of $S$. In other words $q$ is an inverse to $s$. Now by taking the composite function $h$ as $$h:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3:(x,y,z)\mapsto(f_x(q_u(x,y,z), q_v(x,y,z)), f_y(q_u(x,y,z), q_v(x,y,z)), f_z(q_u(x,y,z), q_v(x,y,z))).$$

By computing the Jacobian of $h$ at $(x,y,z)=s(t,v)$ I could obtain an approximation to $J_F$ by computing the partials of on the form: $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial q_u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial q_v}{\partial x}$$ provided that I can find $q$, which it turns out in general I don't because in practice $s$ is a bi-cubic polynomial.

If we rewrite this in matrix notation: $$J_F\approx J_h = J_f\cdot J_q$$  (note that $J_f$ is 3x2 and $J_q$ is 2x3 so the result would be 3x3 as expected) and recall that $q$ is the inverse of $s$ where it is defined, then if $J_s$ would have been square (which it isn't) through the inverse function theorem we could have: $$J_q(s(t,v)) = \left[J_s(t,v)\right]^{-1}.$$

Now as $J_s$ isn't square the inverse isn't defined and my question is. Could I use the pseudo inverse of $J_s$ to compute $J_q$ for use in the above and still have the expected result? If not is there some other way I could go about obtaining an approximation to $J_F$ with what I have?

Note: I do realise that the approximation obtained will be rank 2, or a projection of $J_F$ onto the tangent plane of $S$. This is fine for the application.

Comment: As far as I know, the pseudo inverse of the Jacobian can be used for this multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in general. Here's an example:
$$
s(u, v) = [u, v, 0]
$$

$$
f_1(x, y, z) = x + y + z \\
f_2(x, y, z) = x + y + 2z.
$$
Now
$$
g_1(u, v) = f_1(s(u, v)) = u + v \\
g_2(u, v) = f_2(s(u, v)) = u + v.
$$
So the partials of $g$ wrt $u$ and $v$ (which are the things you denote by 
$$
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial u},
$$
etc.), are identical, but the gradients of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not. Hence the latter cannot be computed from the former.

Comment: If you don't want to compute the Jacobian, perhaps you can rewrite the question (or deleted it and write a new one), since it says "I would like to compute ... the Jacobian."

Comment: BTW, the thing you'll get with the proposed computation is the projection of the Jacobian of $f$ onto the tangent space of the surface, i.e., the surface direction in which to move in order to increase $f$ fastest.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you've just written, but my prior comment at least tells you what you're actually getting, which seems to me to be the thing you probably *ought* to want. :)

Comment: Yeah I'm happy with the Jacobian projected onto the tangent space. To you have any hints on how I could compute that?

Comment: My hint is: "read carefully what I already wrote." (see the "BTW, .." comment.) My other hint is far more serious: Figure out how to express, mathematically, what it is you really want. When you can say it precisely, you may find that you already know how to compute it. Even your clarified question is filled with stuff that doesn't quite make sense. If you're hoping for "I don't want to bother understanding, just tell me what to compute," then I'm the wrong one to provide an answer, but maybe someone else can step up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45145/discussion-between-john-hughes-and-emily-l).